# Android Firebase database: how to retrieve multiple rows?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database structure: [image: json database]

What i am trying to do, is to fill a listView with all the elements in the database, in a custom layout with 3 textView for each line:

Title

Date

Text

---

Title

Date

Text

---

Title

Date

Text

I tried custom adapter, extending FirebaseListAdapter<>,with a class to store the data, but i can't solve this problem.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     your_module_obj=   dataSnapshot1.getValue(Your_module_class_name.class);
                    }
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w("dd", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```